# Want to change processing type as js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my update controller

```
 def update
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @subject.update_attributes(params[:subject])
        @subjects = Subject.all
 #format.html { render :partial => "list"}
        format.js #{ render :js => "$('#list1').html('');"}
      end
    end
  end
```

This is my js file update.js.erb

```
   $('#list1').html('');
   $("#list1").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "list") ) %>");
```

This is the _list.html.erb file, in this using jeditable-rails gem the data is edited.

```
<h1>Listing subjects</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
<th><%=t :Name%></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= editable_field subject, :name, :remote=> true %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', subject %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_subject_path(subject) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', subject, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

This is the Index page where I'm using these index and 'list1' div

```
<div id="list1"><%= render :partial => "list" %></div>
<div id="form"><%= render :partial => 'form' %></div>
```

But my terminal shows

```
Processing by SubjectsController#update as HTML
```

I want to process as JS

Comment: How is called the `update` action ?

Comment: now it is updated in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know Jeditable gem, but according on the example given (https://github.com/afeld/jeditable-rails), it use html format, not js.

If you want to force to js format, you can try this:

```
<%= editable_field subject, :name, :update_url => "#{url_for(object)}.js" %>
```